# Fullcalendar day 24+7hours

Tags: fullcalendar

im looking for way how to change start/end day of day.

For example: day start at 7am and end at 7am next day. In short i need to force calendar thinking day start and end +7hours

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [nextDayThreshold](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/)

"When an event's end time spans into another day, the minimum time it must be in order for it to render as if it were on that day."

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    nextDayThreshold: '07:00:00', // 7am
    ...
});
```